# Problema con la tabla puente en base de datos SQLite

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, datatables, sqlite

Estoy aprendiendo SQL, usando SQLite. Estoy viendo como funcionan las relaciones many-to-many entre tablas que usan primary key y foreign key.

Tengo tres tablas:

`contacts`, que tiene las siguientes columnas: contact_id (primary key), first_name, last_name, email y phone.

`groups`, que tiene las siguientes columnas: group_id (primary_key) y name.

`contact_group`, (mi tabla relacional) con columnas: contact_id (primary key y asociada con foreign key a la de contact_id de `contacts`) y group_id (primary key y asociada con foreign key a la de group_id de `groups`).

Yo puedo meter datos en las tablas de `contacts`de esta forma:

```
insert into contacts (first_name, last_name, email, phone)
values
('jon','sanchez', 'jsan@gmail.com','4433');
```

Y en `groups`así:

```
insert into groups (name)
values
('clase')
```

¿Pero como relleno la tabla relacional `contact_group`?¿cómo le digo que contacto está en cada grupo?¿cómo digo que Jon pertenece al grupo Clase?

Comment: Nada más hacer los inserts te traes el id correspondiente en cada caso y con ellos creas el registro en la tabla relacional. Aqui puedes ver ejemplos para sql https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124863. En sqlite puedes usar select last_insert_rowid(); https://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-autoincrement-insert-value-primary-key

Comment: Esos ejemplos son de como sacar el último id insertado, pero no me aclaran mi pregunta.

Comment: La tabla relacional sera una tabla con dos columnas id_contacto e id_grupo, sacas los ids y haces un insert en la tabla, de este modo puedes saber a que clases pertenece un contacto o que contactos tienen una determinada clase, mediante un select en la tabla contact_group con joins a las otras dos tablas.

Comment: Gracias. Al final lo que he hecho es rellenar la tabla relacional a mano. Y efectivamente, usando joins luego puedo ver el resultado completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he solucionado el problema rellenando manualmente la tabla relacional, dando los id de contact_id y group_id de la siguiente forma:

```
insert into contact_groups (contact_id, groups_id)
values
(3,2)
```

De tal manera, ahí relaciono que el contacto con id = 3 estará en el grupo con id = 2.

Después para ver que todo es correcto y se han relacionado bien he hecho un display de la información tal que así:

```
select *
from groups natural join contact_groups natural join contacts
```

Para que quede más claro dejo aquí las tablas creadas y el resultado del join.

La tabla `groups`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla `contacts`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla relacional de `contact_groups` tras introducir manualmente las relaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente el resultado del join, donde se puede apreciar que la tabla relacional ha hecho bien las conexiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]